# bad data in pyspqrk sql hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use a Hive table with 2.5 billion records in Pyspark.
I assume there is some malformed or otherwise somehow “bad” data in the table.
I am using spark version 1.6.2 with python version 2.6.6:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
with SparkContext() as sc:
    tbl = “mydb.mytable”
    hc = HiveContext(sc)
    df = hc.table(tbl)
```

to read the table.
If I try to run

```
    df.take(5)
```

I meet with a ValueError exception, and

```
    df.count()
```

hangs indefinitely.
However, if I sample the table with:

```
    dfsamp = df.sample(False, 0.0000001, 42)
```

I get a dataframe with around 220 rows, which does not appear to have any problems.
Accessing the full table from the Hive CLI seems to work fine.  I am assuming that there are some records which Spark is for some reason unable to handle.
I am wondering if there is some way to filter a Hive table after loading it as a pyspark dataframe, such that only “good” rows remain.  Alternatively, is there some way that I can preprocess the Hive table before loading it into pyspark, in such a way that I can be sure that it will only contain “good” data?
Appreciate any help / insight.

Comment: Realize now I didn't provide any information about the ValueError.  Here it is: return datetime.date.fromordinal(v + self.EPOCH_ORDINAL) ValueError: ('ordinal must be >= 1', <function <lambda> ...

Comment: You can use [edit] link to update your question when required.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there were some dates in the date columns that were out of range.

If I load the dataframe with

```
df = hc.sql("""
SELECT *
  FROM {0}
  WHERE date_col_1 BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '2029-12-31'
    AND date_col_2 BETWEEN '1970-01-01' AND '2029-12-31'
.
.
.
""".format(tbl)
```

then there is no issue.